# distinguishing customer types in sns countplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have the following graph:

[image]

Ive generated this graph using the following code:

```
temp.gender.value_counts()/len(temp)*100).sort_index().plot(kind="bar", rot=0)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate('{:.2f}%'.format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+0.15, p.get_height()+1))
plt.show()
```

Heres a sample of my data:

```
 customer_id| gender |date_joined
     8540   | Female |2018-08-12
     8544   | Female |
     8540   | Male   |2016-07-14
```

I want to be able to see the within the male and female, how many customers are part of the rewards program. If they have a date_joined value then they are part of the customer rewards program, if they dont have a value for that column then they are not part of the program.

Goal: To visualize of the 56% female and 41% male, how many are part of the rewards program or have a value in date_joined?

Answer (score 0):

The dataframe can be filtered via the 'data_joined' column and used to generate the desired plot:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# generate some dymmy test data; as the exact date isn't important just use two dates
N = 5000
gender = np.random.choice(['Male', 'Female'], N)
data_joined = np.random.choice(['2018-01-01', '2016-01-01', ''], N)

temp = pd.DataFrame({'gender': gender, 'data_joined': data_joined})

ax = (temp.gender.value_counts()/len(temp)*100).sort_index().plot(kind="bar", rot=0, color='lightblue', label='customer')
ax = (temp[temp['data_joined'] != ''].gender.value_counts()/len(temp)*100).sort_index().plot(kind="bar", rot=0, color='crimson', label='reward program', ax=ax)
for p in ax.patches:
    ax.annotate('{:.2f}%'.format(p.get_height()), (p.get_x()+p.get_width()/2, p.get_height()+0.5), ha='center', va='bottom')
ylims = plt.ylim()
plt.ylim(0, ylims[1] + 3) # make room for the labels
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Comment: Was this answer helpful?